# Conditonally recoding data in multiple columns with NA and case_when

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

Data File: -redacted-

I'm working with the ANES 2016 Time Series Study data. Missing data are coded to indicate the reason they are missing, using the following codes and categories:

‐1. Inapplicable
‐2. Text responses available in separate file or coded version will be included in future release
‐3. Restricted
‐4. Error
‐5. Breakoff, sufficient partial IW
‐6. No post‐election interview
‐7. No post data, deleted due to incomplete IW
‐8. Don’t know
‐9. Refused

I want to replace any of these with NAs in my data using case_when and across from the Tidyverse. Here's an example where I try to replace the value 1 in all columns selected with NA. This just returns the orignal data frame. I want to leave data that doesn't match as is.

All the data are formatted as labeled, numeric hence coercing to integer values.

```
#Returns original data frame
anes %>%
  mutate(
    across(V162078:V161522,
           as.integer,
          ~case_when(. == 1 ~ NA_real_,
                     . != 1 ~ .)))

class(anes$V162078)
[1] "labelled" "numeric"
```

```
> dput(head(anes))
structure(list(V160101f = c(0.8877, 1.1605, 0.4161, 0.3852, 0.6931, 
0.7588), V161010e = c("LA", "AR", "MS", "TN", "OH", "NJ"), V162078 = c(15, 
50, 50, 15, 30, 0), V162079 = c(85, 60, 70, 60, 15, 65), V161002 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1), V161003 = c(3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1), V161004 = c(1, 
1, 3, 2, 2, 1), V161005 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), V161006 = c(-1, 
1, -1, 2, 1, 2), V161008 = c(3, 7, 3, 7, 5, 7), V161011 = c(1, 
1, 3, 1, 1, 1), V161019 = c(2, 4, -1, -1, -1, 4), V161020 = c(-1, 
-1, 2, -1, -1, -1), V161021 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), V161021a = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1), V161022 = c(2, 2, -1, 1, 2, 2), V161030 = c(1, 
1, -1, -1, 1, -8), V161080 = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), V161081 = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), V161082 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), V161083 = c(2, 
-8, 2, 2, 2, 2), V161084 = c(2, -8, 2, 2, 2, 2), V161085 = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), V161110 = c(3, 3, 3, 1, 5, 3), V161126 = c(99, 
5, 99, 99, 4, 6), V161128 = c(1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1), V161129 = c(6, 
6, 5, 4, -8, 5), V161146 = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), V161149 = c(2, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 2), V161151x = c(4, 4, 6, 7, 5, 1), V161158x = c(7, 
6, 3, 5, 3, 5), V161204x = c(4, 6, 4, 6, 7, 7), V161215 = c(4, 
4, 4, 2, 5, 5), V161216 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), V161217 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 3, 1), V161223 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1), V161227x = c(4, 
1, 5, 1, 5, 1), V161228x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 4, -8), V161235x = c(5, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 2), V161241 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), V161265x = c(2, 
8, 8, 2, 7, 4), V161267 = c(29, 26, 23, 58, 38, 60), V161268 = c(1, 
6, 6, 1, 4, 2), V161270 = c(9, 13, 9, 9, 9, 14), V161310x = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V161315 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), V161324 = c(1, 
0, 2, 0, 3, 1), V161326 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1), V161361x = c(13, 
17, 6, 20, 3, 1), V161522 = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's what happens if I run it on the raw data without coercion to numeric type:

```
anes %>%
  mutate(
    across(V162078:V161522,
           ~case_when(. == 1 ~ NA_real_,
                      . != 1 ~ .)))

> rlang::last_error()
█
├─<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
│ Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
│ x must have class `numeric`, not class `labelled/numeric`.
│ ℹ Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
└─<error/rlang_error>
  must have class `numeric`, not class `labelled/numeric`.
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
  8. dplyr::case_when(. == 1 ~ NA_real_, . != 1 ~ .)
  9. dplyr:::replace_with(...)
 10. dplyr:::check_class(val, x, name)
 11. dplyr:::glubort(header, "must have class `{exp_classes}`, not class `{out_classes}`.")
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

Final Answer:

```
anes %>%
  mutate(across(V162078:V161522,
    ~case_when(
    . == -1 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -2 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -3 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -4 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -5 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -6 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -7 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -8 ~ NA_real_,
    . == -9 ~ NA_real_,
    . == 99 ~ NA_real_,
    . == 998 ~ NA_real_,
    . == 999 ~ NA_real_,
    TRUE ~ as.numeric((.))))) %>% #This catches all values that are not declared in case_when
  mutate(across(V162078:V161522, as.integer))
```

Comment: IN your `dput`, I didn't find the `labelled` attribute though `class(anes$V162078)#
[1] "numeric"`

Comment: Not sure how to reconcile those outputs. Mutate certainly recognizes the label and freaks out because of it.

Comment: Your code is not giving me the error with the dput showed

Comment: I'm attaching the actual data file in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
anes %>%
  mutate(across(V162078:V161522, as.integer),
         across(V162078:V161522, 
                ~if_else(.x == 1, NA_integer_, .x)))
```

or

```
anes %>%
  mutate(across(V162078:V161522, as.integer),
         across(V162078:V161522, 
                ~case_when(.x == 1 ~ NA_integer_, 
                           TRUE    ~ .x)))
```

or we could test for near-equality using `dplyr::near` so that we can skip the type conversion altogether:

```
anes %>%
  mutate(across(V162078:V161522, 
                ~if_else(near(.x, 1), NA_real_, .x)))
```